# postgres - smart way to select subquery but discard rows where all columns are empty

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a rather large subquery where i want to discard rows where all the values of the subquery (not id) is null

original table:

[image: original tablee1]

desired output:

[image]

Query:

```
SELECT 
  id, num1, num2
FROM table
WHERE COALESCE(num1, num2) IS NOT NULL
```

The query above does the job, but i wondering if there was a smarter / more elegant way of writing this, which does the same as the query above. Since the actual table in question has a lot of columns, i would like avoid, in the future, having to edit a long list of columnnames in a where clause.

Comment: I don't have a problem with your current query.

Comment: i mean it works, but if i have 50 or so columns in the where clause gets harder to maintain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to check if a record of those two columns isn't null:

```
select *
from the_table
where not (num1, num2) is null;
```

`(num1, num2) is null` is true if all fields of the (anonymous) record are null.

Note that it's important to negate the condition, it's not possible to use `is not null` - `(num1, num2) is not null` would **not** work.

I think it's a matter of personal taste which one to use.

Another more dynamic way is to convert the row to a JSON value, remove the irrelevant columns, then remove all null values and compare that to an empty object:

```
select *
from the_table t
where jsonb_strip_nulls(to_jsonb(t) - 'id' - 'num3') <> '{}'
```